# opening a main window in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have the following code. It should open a window of some sort, but nothing happens when i run it or press enter or whatever. what am i doing wrong or what did i forgot?

```
import sys
import tkinter
def main():
root= tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Reminder')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
  tkinter.mainloop()
  if __name__ == '_ _main_ _': 
   main()
 tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: your indentation is incorrect. Is it that way in your read code, too?

Comment: If your code did have any semblance of correct indentation before you pasted it int an SO question surely `if __name__ == '_ _main_ _':` meant that your `main` function was never called.

Comment: You have spaces in your string `'_ _main_ _'`. It should be `'__main__'`

Answer (score 1):

You have to many syntax errors, change your syntax like this

```
from tkinter import *

class Main:
    def __init__ (self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Reminder")
        self.root.geometry("222x222")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    obj = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You called tkinter.mainloop(). What you should be doing is root.mainloop().

```
import sys                  #imports
import tkinter
def main():
    root= tkinter.Tk()      #Setup root
    root.title('Reminder')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.mainloop()         #Culprit
if __name__ == '_ _main_ _': 
    main()

root.mainloop()             #Culprit
```

Also, usually you only need one mainloop, not two, as mainloop runs until you kill the window.

Hope that helps! (:

Comment: Sorry but is does not??

Comment: @thales78 You have a bunch of issues, as others have mentioned. One of which is that tkinter.mainloop() is wrong. it should be root.mainloop().

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an actual widget to the root.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")   

        self.parent = parent        
        self.parent.title('Reminder')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

if you use

```
if __name__ == '_ _main_ _': 
    main()
```

Your `main` will never run. It should be `__main__`. You can convince yourself of this in an interactive session.

```
stacey@stacey-Inspiron-N4020:~$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> __name__
'__main__'
>>> __name__ == '__main__'
True
>>> __name__ == '_ _main_ _'
False
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

The first problem I see in your code is the import statement at least for python2.7, it should be:

import Tkinter

Anyway, that code doesnt seem to work, so I thought you could use some example that does show a window:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
            command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```

Anyway you have spaces in your:

```
if __name__ == '_ _main_ _':
```

and it should be

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Comment: Ok, but gives me a solution, but i want to know why the code given by me does not work? The capital T does not help. It even says it error does not know Tkinter?

Comment: `import tkinter` (lowercase t) is correct for python 3.x.

Comment: Op didnt say he was using python3

Comment: Yes it works at the moment, i am not sure why. id tried several __ _ _ etc but suddenly it works. Anyway thanks to you all!

Comment: I tried several things until I noticed nothing was being executed, if you found my answer helpful or at least appreciate my effort please mark it as answered